# enum in class doesn't change when call own function

Tags: c++, class, enums

## Short Problem Description

I have a problem that is when I change a enum but it doesn't change.
It looks like just a local change.

if I do the below quote is fine.

```
level = new level_1();
while(true)
{
    cout << level->state << endl; // show '1' at first loop. Another loop show '2'
    level->state = STATE_INITIALIZE;
}
```

but I have to change state in his function

```
level = new level_1();
while(true)
{
    cout << level->state << endl; // show '1' only
    level.do();
}
```

level.do function

```
void Level_1::do()
{
    state = STATE_INITIALIZE; // If this work, it should be '2'
    // this->state = STATE_INITIALIZE;
}
```

so this is a big problem for me it doesn't change!! T_T

---

## Long Code

this is some code (almost full code)

## Level.h

```
enum LEVEL_STATE
{       STATE_LOAD = 1,
        STATE_INITIALIZE = 2,
        STATE_UPDATE = 3,
        STATE_DRAW = 4,
        STATE_FREE = 5,
        STATE_UNLOAD = 6
};

class Level {
public:
    LEVEL_STATE state = STATE_LOAD;
    vector<Shader> shader;
    vector<Model> model;
    virtual void load()=0;
    virtual void initialize()=0;
    virtual void update()=0;
    virtual void draw(Shader)=0;
    virtual void free()=0;
    virtual void unload()=0;
    virtual Level* next()=0;
};
```

## Map_Level_1.h

```
#include"Level.h"

class Level_1 : public Level {
public:
    LEVEL_STATE state;
    vector<Shader> shader;
    vector<Model> model;
    void load();
    void initialize();
    void update();
    void draw(Shader);
    void free();
    void unload();
    Level* next();
};
```

## Map_Level_1.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include"Map_Level_0.h"
#include"Map_Level_1.h"

extern Camera camera;
extern float SCR_WIDTH;
extern float SCR_HEIGHT;

void Level_1::load()
{
    shader.push_back(Shader("../Shader/alpha.vertex", "../Shader/alpha.fragment")); // this worked!
    model.push_back(Model (FileSystem::getPath("res/arcade/arcade.obj"))); // this worked!
    state = STATE_INITIALIZE; // this is not worked! the value doesn't change!
}

void Level_1::initialize()
{
    shader[0].use();
    state = STATE_UPDATE; // this is not worked! the value doesn't change!
}

void Level_1::update()
{
    shader[0].use();
    state = STATE_DRAW; // this is not worked! the value doesn't change!
}

void Level_1::draw(Shader shader)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 model;

    shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
    shader.setMat4("view", view);
    shader.setInt("mode", 0);

    //model = scale(vec3(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f));
    shader.setMat4("model", model);
    shader.setInt("fragMode", 1);
    shader.setVec3("fragColor", vec3(0.92f, 0.92f, 0.92f));
    this->model[0].Draw(shader);
    state = STATE_UPDATE; // this is not worked! the value doesn't change!
}

void Level_1::free()
{

}

void Level_1::unload()
{

}

Level* Level_1::next() {
    return new Level_0();
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
level = new Level_1();
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    DEV_processInput(window);

    cout << level->state;
    switch (level->state)
    {
    case STATE_LOAD:
        level->load();
    case STATE_INITIALIZE:
        level->initialize();
    case STATE_UPDATE:
        level->update();
    case STATE_DRAW:
        level->draw(shader_1);
    case STATE_FREE:
        level->free();
    case STATE_UNLOAD:
        level->unload();
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

---

If I
1.) do something wrong that it is easy to fix
2.) repeat any questions

I will apologize..

Comment: Please extract an MCVE, as per site guidelines.

Comment: You do know that `switch` cases ***fall through***? That you need a `break` between cases?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I check cout << level->state; it is always '1' it is impossible because I increase every function call in case so next loop should not '1' T_T

Comment: You split object's initialization into several stages, and they are called from the outside sequentially in always the same sequence that is nevertheless (predictably) resolved based on an object's public member variable that indicates current (still non-ready) state. Looks like a saucerful of antipatterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a `state` member in the base class, then redefined the same member in subclasses, which leads to the issue.

If you have a `Level * level` pointer, no matter which subclass instance it is pointing to, you always read **the base class** `state` member, while you write to **the subclass member** in their methods (i.e. `do`).

I suggest to define `state` in the base class only (and make it `protected`, maybe).

Comment: ahhhhh I got it! thanks